# What skills are affected by critical hit chance?

Tags: guild-wars-2

For example, a Guardian has five skills of which four damage an enemy. Does critical hit chance effect on all of them, or do only certain skills get affected by critical hit chance (like the very first skill, 'autoattack')?

I'm thinking of going full precision/power build but it depends on if all skills benefit from critical hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All damaging abilities can critically strike.

Damaging conditions, however, (bleed, poison, fire, etc) cannot.

Comment: Allright then, full Berserker with Ruby Orbs, here I come.

Comment: Remember to get really, really good at dodging and evades, because you'll go down if someone sneezes on you :P

Comment: @Gwen Being a guardian helps though :)

Comment: In addition to Raven's answer you can check for yourself in game: as you use different skills pay attention to your target and notice the damage numbers. The critical hits have a small blood splatter type of effect behind the white numbers.